# ORDER BY percentage is not working

Tags: mysql, join, sql-order-by

I'm doing a query in MySQL and results are not ordered by the percentage. How can I force order by percentage? It is ordered by `total_sold`, but not by percentage.

Here is the code:

```
     SELECT in_disassembly.car_id, 
            in_disassembly.cost, 
            IFNULL(SUM(product_sold.product_total_price),0) AS total_sold,
            concat((IFNULL(SUM(product_sold.product_total_price),0)
                            /in_disassembly.cost * 100)) AS percentage_sold
       FROM in_disassembly
 INNER JOIN product_sold ON product_sold.product_car_id = in_disassembly.car_id
      WHERE in_disassembly.car_id > $start_id AND in_disassembly.car_id < $end_id
   GROUP BY in_disassembly.car_id 
   ORDER BY percentage_sold
```

FIXED CODE

```
SELECT in_disassembly.car_id, in_disassembly.cost, IFNULL(SUM(product_sold.product_total_price),0) AS total_sold, ROUND((IFNULL(SUM(product_sold.product_total_price),0)/in_disassembly.cost * 100),0) AS percentage_sold
           FROM in_disassembly
           INNER JOIN product_sold ON product_sold.product_car_id = in_disassembly.car_id
           WHERE in_disassembly.car_id > $start_id AND in_disassembly.car_id < $end_id GROUP BY in_disassembly.car_id ORDER BY percentage_sold DESC
```

Comment: ORDER BY percentage_sold +0 Note that CONCAT serves no useful purpose. Concatenation can always be done in application code.

Comment: You know you're using a nonstandard MySQL extension of `GROUP BY`, right? This can generate bizarre results.  Read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making a string there with CONCAT so it will be sorted as string. That is, 1 followed by 11 followed by 2.

Comment: Thanks you are right made the number an interget now its getting order correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ASC or DESC after ORDER BY percentage_sold

Comment: That should not be a problem, default is asc.

Answer (score 0):

Try without concatenating the percent to a string and it should work.